# "host lookup did not complete" error

Tags: domain-name-system, email, exim

I need to send mail from sub.domain.com but delivery to one address fails with an error "R=lookuphost defer (-1): host lookup did not complete".

Additional information that might be relevant: 
My /etc/resolv.conf contains nameservers of a VPS provider (different from domain provider's nameservers). 
I also checked DNS records of the addressee and found out there was no MX record for it.

Comment: You should explain what the problem is, not [what you think the solution is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912).

Comment: 1. Just because there is no MX record, it does not mean that mail cannot be sent there an A record is valid in absence of an MX record. 2. Does this VPS provider's DNS do recursive lookups for you?

Comment: @NickW I think it does not do recursive lookup. I checked it by "host mysubdomain.domain.com vps_providers_nameserver" and it returned REFUSED; also dig nameserver mysubdomain.domain.com returned "recursion requested but not available"

Comment: That's not good, you want to configure a DNS server that will do recursive lookups for you, especially if you want to run a mailserver.

Comment: thank you @NickW I can't upvote your comments but you've been very helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check if MX DNS resolution fails from your side or not with [mxtoolbox.com](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx)

- if you don't have MX results. exim should fallback to A record. cf [exim FAQ](https://github.com/Exim/exim/wiki/Q0310) (check Q0311 too)

use `exim -bt -d-resolver user@example.org` to diagnose exim mail routing

- if yes. it means DNS resolution fails on your side.

run `nslookup -type=MX example.org` on your server.
and check if you get MX records answers.

if not, try the same request but specify a well known nameserver, like google public dns:
`nslookup -type=MX example.org 8.8.8.8`

you should now get some MX results, and it means your nameserver is not working properly. So you can change your resolv.conf to a nameserver that works properly (provider, google dns, what you want, ..) or setup your own

Comment: thank you! If I don't get any MX results for subdomain.example.com but get them for example.com, does it count?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. the only one fallback is A record

Comment: one last question! if exim -bt -d-resolver user@example1.org succeeds but exim -bt -d-resolver user@example2.org fails, doesn't it mean that the problem is with example2.org and not with me?

Comment: besides, when I do dig  @8.8.8.8 example2.org I get status: SERVFAIL and no answer section. And example2.org is the only domain I'm having such problems with, all my other addressees are able to get emails from me

Comment: it means the nameserver of example2.org is unreachable, misconfigured. the problem is not on your side